# Checking equality of two strings is not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, recursion

```
function playerSelection() {
     let choice = prompt("Enter you choice.");
     while(choice != "rock" && choice != "paper" && choice != "scissor"){
        alert("Wrong entry");
        playerSelection();
     }
return choice;
   }
```

This code works just fine until you enter a string that makes the while loop condition true. Once it enters the while loop after an incorrect entry and prompts you to enter another string even if you enter a correct string, it keeps displaying the "wrong entry" alert and shows the prompt until you reload the page. What is going on?

I tried manipulating the logical operator but that does not seem to help. My guess is it has something to do with the recursion, but I have no clue what it is.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: please edit your question and try to put your code here

Comment: I have edited the question and add those two lines   ```let result = playerSelection();
            alert(result);``` to launch it immediately.
In a snippet that cause a loop because the variable choice must be declared outside the function. So like in my answer if you declare ```let choice``` then write the ```function...``` the code is running normally

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thank you. I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: Why don't you use buttons to choose between "rock", "paper"and "scissor"???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable should be declared before the function as here :

```js
            let choice;
            function playerSelection(){
            choice = prompt("Enter your choice.");
            while(choice != "rock" && choice != "paper" && choice != "scissor"){
                alert("Wrong entry");
                playerSelection();
            }
            return choice;
            }

            let result = playerSelection();
            alert("result = " + result);
```

Comment: I see. So, in my mistaken code, is it because the "choice" that "return" accesses is always the one initially entered and not the updated one?

Comment: @Mahdu : Exactly !!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call the function again. The "prompt"-method already does what you (as I am guessing) want to do.
Do this instead:

```js
function playerSelection(){
    let choice;
    do{
        choice = prompt("Enter your choice: ");
        if(choice != "rock" && choice != "paper" && choice != "scissor"){
            alert("Wrong entry!");
        }
    }while(choice != "rock" && choice != "paper" && choice != "scissor");
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

it's because each new call to `playerSelection()` creates a new call context that stores its own local variables and parameters. try this out:

```
playerSelection() {
    let choice = prompt('Enter your choice:')

    while (choice != 'rock' && choice != 'paper' && choice != 'scissors') {
        alert('Wrong entry')
        choice = prompt('Enter your choice:')
    }

    return choice
}
```

or if you want with recursion

```
playerSelection() {
    let choice = prompt('Enter your choice:')

    if (choice == 'rock' || choice == 'paper' || choice == 'scissors') {
        return choice
    } else {
        alert('wrong entry')
        return playerSelection()
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help!